# Finitary mono preserving functors on varieties that fail to preserve intersections.

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $Alg$ be a single-sorted finitary variety i.e. one specified by a set $\Sigma$ of operations with finite arity and also a set $E$ of equations, the morphisms being the usual $\Sigma$-algebra morphisms.

Further let $T : Alg \to Alg$ be a finitary functor that preserves monos (injections) and empty binary intersections i.e. $T(A \cap B) = TA \cap TB$ whenever $A \cap B = \emptyset$. This trivially holds if $\Sigma$ contains a constant.

Then my question is:

*Does there exist such a $T$ that fails to preserve finite or infinite intersections?*

Note that every $T : Set \to Set$ preserves non-empty finite intersections by page 3 of:

http://www.iti.cs.tu-bs.de/~adamek/presentation.AGT.pdf

so under my assumptions $T$ would preserve finite intersections. Then if $T$ is finitary this can be shown to imply preservation of infinite intersections. Therefore no such example can be found in $Set$, this being the variety where $\Sigma = E = \emptyset$.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: The endofunctor T of Set sending a set X to a singleton 1 if it is non-empty, and to the empty set 0 if it is empty preserves monomorphisms, since it sends *every* map to a monomorphism. But it does not preserve the intersection of the two maps from a singleton 1 to a two-element set 2. 

Comment: @Steve: Thanks. However I was intending to exclude this case because one can alter the functor so that it does preserve finite intersections, whilst preserving the structure of $T$-algebras and $T$-coalgebras. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Rob, I'm not sure quite what this means. I take it that the modified version sends everything to 1? In that case the empty set will no longer possess an algebra structure.

Comment: Ok, you are again correct. In "Terminal coalgebras in well-founded set theory" Barr shows one can alter $T : Set \to Set$ on $\emptyset$ to ensure it preserves monos, so that the $T$-algebras and $T'$-algebras are isomorphic. However he assumes $T\emptyset \neq \emptyset$, which excludes your example. A similar construction for finite interesection preservation is given here: http://www.iti.cs.tubs.de/~adamek/presentation.AGT.pdf (page 4), which explicitly mentions your example. Really I am looking to exclude such cases i.e. failure to preserve *empty* intersections.

Comment: An empty intersection of subobjects is the whole object, so is always preserved. The example I gave involved failure to preserve a binary intersection. 

Perhaps it would be helpful if you explained what you were really after. 

Comment: No, the reason your functor fails to preserve binary intersections is that it fails to preserves empty intersections. That is, the image of the two maps from 1 to 2 have empty intersection, so: $T(A \cap B) = T\emptyset = \emptyset$ whereas $TA \cap TB = 1 \cap 1 = 1$. In fact this is the only reason why $Set$ functor can fail to preserve finite intersections, as proved in the paper I linked to.

Comment: Oh and sorry if the terminology 'empty intersection' was a bit misleading, I see now that it was unclear.

Comment: @Steve: Here is some motivation. In coalgebra (i.e. $T$-coalgebras for a functor) one can often define a notion of generated subcoalgebras. This is done by assuming the functor preserves infinite intersections, allowing one to define the weight of a transition $t \in TA$ as the least subalgebra $B \subseteq A$ s.t. $t$ lies in the embedding of $TB$ into $TA$. I have been developing a generic framework of rational fixpoint expressions parametric in a functor $T : Alg \to Alg$. But I am yet to find a functor obeying the constraints in my question that fails to preserve infinite intersections.